# How to cluster my data with binary variables?

Tags: r, clustering, distance

I have a dataset like df and I want to cluster the data in R. These variables are binary showing that a person uses a programming language or not. I have these questions:

1- How can I visualize my data? Up to now, I tried heatmap (with clusters on both rows and columns)

2- What is the best distance calculation method for this data?

3- What is the best clustering method for this data?

4- Should I consider normalizing the variables i.e. (value-mean)/sd before clustering? All the variables are either zero or one but the variables have different standard deviations.

```
  language <- c(
  "R, Matlab",
  "Assembly, R, Go, Rust",
  "Java, Javascript, Ruby, SQL",
  "Java, Ruby",
  "C, C++",
  "PHP, Javascript, Ruby, Assembly, Swift, R, Matlab, Go, Haskell",
  "R",
  "Perl, Javascript, R",
  "Javascript, Ruby, Bash",
  "Python, PHP, Javascript",
  "Java",
  "Java, C"
)

df <-as.data.frame(language,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df <- reshape2::recast(
  data =  setNames(strsplit(language, ", ", T), language), 
  formula = L1~value, 
  fun.aggregate = length
)

str(df)
```

Comment: Did you first try to search `clustering binary` for Q/A aready posted on this site?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my answers your questions:

4- If your variables are all either 0 or 1 you should not have to normalize.

2- There are many distance calculation methods available. My default one is Euclidean distance (for environmental variables) but you should look to find one appropriate for binary variables.

1- You can try non-metric multidimensional scaling using the package `vegan` to visualize your selected distance matrix. At the end, you'll have a 2D plot of each of your samples and the points closer will be the most similar ones while the points farther will be the most dissimilar ones.

3- I previously used the software `PRIMER` to do clustering analysis and the package `clustsig` seems to be doing pretty much the same thing in `R`. You should look into this package to perform your clustering analysis.

Comment: Paragraph "4" mixes two different meanings of "scale". Paragraphs "2", "3" - euclidean distance is quite rarely used with binary data, there is a great number of coefficients specifically for binary data.

Comment: @ttnphns can you develop on what you mean by "2 different meanings of scale". I agree with you there can be better distance than Euclidean for binary data. Any suggestions?

Comment: z-standardization - which is the normalization method discussed by OP - is centering and bringing st. dev. to 1. "Scale" may mean st. dev., and in this sense the binary variables which had different "scale" now have unit "scale". Another meaning of "scale" is the binary 2-grade measuring scale itself. In this sense, all the variables were initially on the same "scale"; but after standardization their measuring scale, while still dichotomous (2 values), is no more the same (by those values) for the variables.